# Can HIMEM.SYS be disabled in Windows ME’s IO.SYS?

Tags: ms-dos, windows-me

Windows ME's IO.SYS includes HIMEM.SYS, which it loads unconditionally. Since it is possible to decompress and disassemble IO.SYS, and hack it to enable full DOS mode, can we go a step further and modify it to *not* load the built-in HIMEM.SYS automatically?

Some info on decompressing and disassembling IO.SYS can be found here: [Disassembling Windows IO.SYS](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/15479/24522)

Comment: You might want to register your account, so you can log in again later. Otherwise, if your browser loses your login cookies, you won't be able to edit your own question and stuff like that.

Comment: I've edited your question a bit. If you don't like my edits, you can roll them back, or click [edit] to make further changes. Also, I found [an MSFN thread](https://msfn.org/board/topic/77019-windows-me-iosys-winbootsys-format/page/2/) where some people were discussing this kind of thing (removing unused code from io.sys).

Comment: The built-in XMS driver seems relatively easy to disable by patching three bytes, but… why would you want to? All it gets you is a crippled DOS.

Comment: I want to have an option at startup to run a pure dos without any memory managers. Rarely needed but useful feature. 
Which three bytes ? Can I load himem.sys from config.sys after that?

Comment: someone actually uses Win ME ? As I remember it was unstable and unusable on every machine I encounter back in the days ... did they patch it? to point it was usable ?

Comment: Yes, in my case Me is the most stable. My retro pc has 3 sound cards, network card, scsi controller and voodoo 3. All of which coexist nicely both in dos and windows.

Comment: I think you should try this, a driver to help loading EMM386.exe in MS-DOS 8.0 https://github.com/pufengdu/IO8EMMOK

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That the IO.SYS of Windows Me includes an integrated HIMEM.SYS is something of a simplification.  What is true is that IO.SYS includes a built-in XMS driver; but even if it was derived from code originally written for HIMEM.SYS, it cannot really be considered a discrete unit any more.  Other code in the DOS kernel assumes it is present and working, and will fail if that assumption is broken.  It is arguably simply just another integral part of the DOS kernel.

Still, it’s relatively easy to disable that built-in driver.  Assuming you have uncompressed the file, it’s enough to patch three bytes:

```
--- original
+++ patched
@@ -117,7 +117,7 @@
 000008a0  b8 00 70 00 c0 a0 62 02  8c 02 4c 50 54 33 20 20  |..p...b...LPT3  |
 000008b0  20 20 01 ea 00 00 00 00  ca 00 70 00 00 80 62 02  |  ........p...b.|
 000008c0  99 02 43 4f 4d 32 20 20  20 20 dc 00 70 00 00 80  |..COM2    ..p...|
-000008d0  62 02 9f 02 43 4f 4d 33  20 20 20 20[50 04]70 00  |b...COM3    P.p.|
+000008d0  62 02 9f 02 43 4f 4d 33  20 20 20 20[ff ff]70 00  |b...COM3    ..p.|
 000008e0  00 80 62 02 a5 02 43 4f  4d 34 20 20 20 20 e8 ba  |..b...COM4    ..|
 000008f0  01 f2 07 e8 b5 01 b2 0c  85 03 18 12 00 00 00 00  |................|
 00000900  10 00 00 00 00 13 00 00  00 00 15 00 00 00 00 19  |................|
@@ -6567,7 +6567,7 @@
 0001ee20  e8 0a 66 c1 ea 0a e8 66  00 66 0b db 75 9c 66 83  |..f....f.f..u.f.|
 0001ee30  3e c5 00 01 07 c3 1e 06  1f 8b 0e fa 34 8b 1e fc  |>...........4...|
 0001ee40  34 66 33 c0 c6 07 04 88  47 01 66 89 47 02 66 89  |4f3.....G.f.G.f.|
-0001ee50  47 06 83 c3 0a e2 ed 89  1e 00 35 1f c3[1e]66 50  |G.........5...fP|
+0001ee50  47 06 83 c3 0a e2 ed 89  1e 00 35 1f c3[cb]66 50  |G.........5...fP|
 0001ee60  66 b8 00 00 ff ff 8e d8  b8 04 32 66 87 06 bc 00  |f.........2f....|
 0001ee70  66 26 a3 fc 31 66 b8 8d  32 ff ff 66 87 06 54 00  |f&..1f..2..f..T.|
 0001ee80  66 26 a3 f8 31 b8 ff ff  e8 a0 00 66 58 1f cb 66  |f&..1......fX..f|
```

The particular offsets where those bytes are found may differ (depending on the version of IO.SYS you have), but the surrounding data should be pretty much exactly the same.  What this does is:

- It disconnects the `XMSXXXX0` character device header from the linked list of built-in drivers;
- It disables hooking interrupt vectors 0x2f and 0x15 that would otherwise allow accessing XMS driver services.

The XMS driver code still occupies conventional memory, but is completely inert, and will not be found by software looking for it.  A virtual machine booted from an Emergency Boot Disk floppy image with such a modified IO.SYS superficially seems relatively stable, with the `MEM` command behaving as if no XMS driver were present.  And by ‘relatively stable’, I mean that if the CONFIG.SYS file contains both `DOS=HIGH,UMB` and loads the DISPLAY.SYS device driver, the system hangs at boot.  Clearly there is some code somewhere else within that version of DOS that blindly assumes that the XMS driver is always present and enabled.  And why would it not?  Until now, it indeed was.  (Attempting to launch the VMM32, i.e. the graphical, protected-mode part of Windows Me under this modified kernel also fails, and not especially gracefully, but that was probably to be expected.)

So to keep the system working robustly (as much as DOS can be robust), you would probably need to also insert some code to account for the possibility that the XMS driver is missing.  But to me, that starts to seem like adding functionality instead of removing it.  It makes the kernel less stable, and it doesn’t even gain you anything to do this, other than being able to scrub the now non-functional code with zeroes, so that the kernel may compress better (and even that is only on-disk).

To fully excise the XMS driver from the DOS kernel and reclaim its memory, you would have to perform a complete disassembly of the whole kernel, remove the XMS code, and then assemble it back (while fixing surrounding code to no longer unconditionally assume its existence).  This is not an insurmountable task, but a pretty laborious one, so I would not find it particularly appealing in light of alternative solutions: to simply downgrade to MS-DOS 7.10, or to switch to another DOS kernel, which allows you to use any XMS driver you wish, including none.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent loading of the xms code completely and would that allow for loading himem.sys manually from config.sys file? My goal is to add a clean dos mode but not at the cost of crippled xms functionality.

Comment: Start an annotated disassembly project, correctly identify all in-code offsets, and then excise the XMS driver and XMS-dependent code from it. But honestly, you’d be better off just running another DOS than creating your own Frankenstein version.

Comment: Ok, understood. I appreciate your expertise. Couldn’t find any solutions to the problem and now I know why.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it can be disabled. Check my MSFN thread:

https://msfn.org/board/topic/183250-how-to-disable-the-built-in-xms-driver-in-windows-mes-iosys/

In summary, what you need to do is to knock out the subroutine call instruction that installs the built-in XMS driver.

Warning: Disabling the built-in XMS driver will make your real-mode DOS VERY unstable.

However, if what you want to do is load another HIMEM.SYS so that you can load EMM386.EXE, you should instead use my driver IO8EMMOK.SYS. Here:

https://github.com/pufengdu/IO8EMMOK

Though this driver does not disable or remove the built-in XMS driver, it converts it to a normal-behaved, invisible but simple HIMEM.SYS, which always resides in HMA. In case that the built-in Windows Me real-mode XMS driver causes trouble, this will be the most simple way to make use of it, instead of removing it. My driver only takes 1xx bytes memory. It does not require you to decompress Windows Me's IO.SYS.

Some more explanations:
The reason why the built-in XMS driver does not behave like a normal HIMEM.SYS is: by default, the driver always resides in HMA. In Windows Me, the A20 gate MUST be kept ON at all times. If any other program tries to access any XMS driver function with A20 off, the system will hang. My IO8EMMOK driver takes over basic XMS driver calls in the conventional memory, and checks if A20 is on. If so, it forwards the call to the real XMS driver; otherwise, it turns on A20, forwards the call, then turns off A20 again.

Seems like my last answer was too simple to be kept as an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing! …belatedly. I thought the older post didn’t quite fit as an answer because it wasn’t clear how it related to the question asked; but with the explanation you gave here, it actually looks quite good, even if it’s not a direct answer.