# Why are there three different settings in the [Paths] section of MSDOS.SYS?

Tags: windows-98, windows-95, windows-me

In Windows 9x, the MSDOS.SYS configuration file contains a `[Paths]` section whose contents usually look like this:

```
[Paths]
WinDir=C:\WINDOWS
WinBootDir=C:\WINDOWS
HostWinBootDrv=C
```

Both `WinDir` and `WinBootDir` point to the Windows installation directory, which usually is `C:\WINDOWS`, and `HostWinBootDrv` points to the drive letter containing it. Having distinct settings suggests that potentially these could be different. Are there situations where this is the case? Why are there three different settings at all? What is their purpose anyway?

Answer (score 12):

`HostWinBootDrv` is the easiest to explain: it has to do with disk compression, i.e. DoubleSpace/DriveSpace. What DriveSpace does is create a file with a name like `DRVSPACE.nnn` (with `nnn` being a three-digit number) that contains the compressed contents of the disk. The compressed file system is assigned the drive letter of the partition containing the file, and the latter (called the *host drive* in this context) is assigned another drive letter, or sometimes hidden entirely. If the partition from which Windows starts is compressed, `HostWinBootDrv` points to the host drive of that partition, which by default is `H`, while the other settings point to the compressed file system.

---

As for `WinDir` and `WinBootDir`, what they do is relatively easy to discover. Some experimentation reveals the following:

`WinDir` points to the directory in which Windows is installed. The presence of `WinDir` in `MSDOS.SYS` is what instructed `IO.SYS` (before Windows Me) that there was a Windows installation present that it should be prepared to launch (as opposed to just booting to a command prompt, like on an emergency boot floppy). If `WinDir` is set, the real-mode kernel will do the following:

- Put two entries in the `PATH` environment variable: the directory pointed to by `WinDir` and its subdirectory `COMMAND`;
- Create a subdirectory `TEMP` under this directory and point the environment variables `TEMP` and `TMP` to it;
- Clear a flag, returned by interrupt `0x2f` service `0x1611` in BL register bit 5, which `COMMAND.COM` checks to decide whether to launch `WIN.COM` after processing `AUTOEXEC.BAT`;
- Start the device configuration manager before processing `CONFIG.SYS` (this can be suppressed by the `SystemReg=0` setting in the `[Options]` section)
- Look for certain critical files in this directory, including `SYSTEM.DAT` (the Registry), `COMMAND.COM` (which will fall back to the root directory if absent) and real-mode drivers like `HIMEM.SYS` and `IFSHLP.SYS` (which can be suppressed by setting `DOS=NOAUTO` in `CONFIG.SYS`);
- Store the directory itself in the `winbootdir` environment variable (all-lowercase!).

The last two of these is what can be overridden by setting `WinBootDir`: if that setting is present as well, those files will be looked up in `WinBootDir` instead, and of course it’s that directory which will end up in the `winbootdir` environment variable.

There are some wrinkles here however, for example with respect to `WIN.COM`. When the `AUTOEXEC.BAT` file is absent, empty or being skipped (like e.g. in Safe Mode), `COMMAND.COM` is not loaded and the real-mode kernel will instead directly execute `WIN.COM` from `WinBootDir`. However, if `AUTOEXEC.BAT` is present, `COMMAND.COM` will be launched to process it, after which it will in turn execute the command `WIN`, launching `WIN.COM`… by looking it up in `PATH`, which by default points to `WinDir`.

---

Well, great, but why are `WinDir` and `WinBootDir` separate settings at all? It is still not entirely clear to me, but from what little I can gather, it was probably meant to support booting Windows over a LAN. In such a configuration, DOS would first be loaded from a normal file system (or even itself from a disk image downloaded over the network), load essential drivers like `HIMEM.SYS` from `WinBootDir` located on the same file system, then load DOS network drivers, map a share (containing `WinDir`) to its drive letter, and then continue booting from there. If that’s the intended scenario, then even the `WIN.COM` oddity starts making sense now: there could be a ‘main’ Windows copy started when booting normally from `WinDir`, and another minimal ‘emergency’ copy booted in Safe Mode from `WinBootDir`, when network boot fails.

In any case, the requirements of this scenario could easily require those two settings to have different values. Here’s a short fragment from [a document](ftp://blurredmanswebsite.ddns.net/Drivers/Mainboards/ECS_K7VZA/Peripheral/Lan/Davicom/Bootrom/BOOTROM.TXT) describing just such a configuration:

> ```
> D-2. MSDOS.SYS Sample File for DM9102 :
> =======================================
>
>       [Paths]
>       WinDir=g:\client1
>       WinBootDir=d:\winboot     <== According to RAMDRIVE.SYS assign
>       HostWinBootDrv=c              Virtual Drive (D: or E:)
> ```

There is also a [paper](https://www.matem.unam.mx/%7Emicho/papers/Ripl.pdf) and a series of articles by Micho Durdevich ([part 1](https://www.matem.unam.mx/%7Emicho/ripl1.html), [2](https://www.matem.unam.mx/%7Emicho/ripl2.html), [3](https://www.matem.unam.mx/%7Emicho/ripl3.html), [4](https://www.matem.unam.mx/%7Emicho/ripl4.html), [5](https://www.matem.unam.mx/%7Emicho/ripl5.html) and [6](https://www.matem.unam.mx/%7Emicho/ripl6.html)) that describe how to achieve network boot with Windows 9x.

They are somewhat scant on the details of how this all worked, but both those sources mention a `SETMDIR` utility, which is distributed as part of Windows 95. This implies that network booting was probably a use case intended by Microsoft.

Comment: If you run DOS by itself, windir is not created, and you get winblotdir and its subdirectory command.  WIn is just any command.  You can use a command that says 'hello world' there.

Answer (score 2):

Winbootdir points to the directory that DOS startup files are in.  It can be different to Windir.

Windir points to the directory that the user's registry is in.  On a network this can be different to where windows is installed.

Winbootdir is used if there is no config.sys/autoexec.bat, to load the drivers like himem.sys, ifs$hlp.sys, and co.  It could be on a boot image sent through the network, for example.

Windir as in 3.0, needs to contain win.com, but win.com is then responsible for starting windows (by running win32.vxd or something.)

== Edit ==

http://reboot.pro/topic/22047-dual-boot-msdos-710-and-630/

This post describes the creation of a minimal DOS setup, using the DOS from Win98se, and a slightly modified MS-DOS 6.22.

Exanples of what happens when winbootdir and windir are changed.  The command setmdir changes windir after the system is booted, we are not using it here.

http://reboot.pro/topic/18130-ms-dos-7-help-file/

This topic contains the working comments for creating a qbasic help file for DOS 5 to 7 (ie as a replacement for what's on the CDROM).

https://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=34798&p=401645#p401645

This is where we are documenting running multiple Windows 9x versions as options in the config.sys.  So far we have overcome most of the problems in launching Win95 from DOS98SE.

https://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=41489

This is progress on running Windows 95 and ME from DOS98SE.  It has a link to the DOS files used in the experiments.

All of these experiments are based on VPC sessions that do what is described.  For example, after Offer posted the construction of c:\MSDOS7, i ran the experiment with several NT5x over the top of different Win98 and ME installs, in English and in German.  It's where I got the idea of using c:\msdos7 from.

Comment: ‘Windir points to the directory that the user's registry is in’ — wrong, and I checked this. For example, interrupt 0x2f service 0x1613 returns a path in WinBootDir. The rest of this answer is so sloppy and vague that I seriously doubt its usefulness.

Comment: Except, this is based on actual setups.  A dos7 booted without windows has a winbootdir but no windir.  The utility setmdir is a network utility for changing windir.  See http://reboot.pro/topic/22047-dual-boot-msdos-710-and-630/ for one of the experiments.

Comment: You can run Windows 3.1 and 98, if you separate the DOS out of Win98 (eg to msdos7), point winbootdir to c:\msdos7, and windir to '.',  This is how Wengier's DOS 7,1 does it,  To start either version of windows, change to the windows directory and type 'win'.  A fault exists in the Win31 win386.exe that garbles the dos dir after exit, if not in the root directory, but a patch exists for this.  In such a system the registry (in win98, it's system.dat and user.dat, not 'registry.dat'), is not found, and windir is not set in DOS, but by Windows.

Comment: ‘A dos7 booted without windows has a winbootdir but no windir’ — also wrong, when the `WinDir` setting is absent, `WinBootDir` is ignored even if present. DOS boot floppies created by Windows 9x lack either.

Comment: If you install NT5 or later over Windows 98 or ME, then there is a directory of DOS files, left in c:\msdos7.  To this, there is also some files in the root directory (io.sys, msdos.sys and boot.dos).  Boot.dos is to be added to the NT boot.ini.  MSDOS.SYS contains pointers to windir and winbootdir toc:\MSDOS7, with logo=0 and bootgui=0.  The environment created can be seen (and changed), in IO.SYS.  The environment contains TMP, TEMP, PROMPT, winbootdir, PATH and COMSPEC.  The PATH contains C:\MSDOS7;C:\MSDOS7\COMMAND.

Comment: What do Windows 3.1 or NT5 have to do with anything? The question is clearly about Windows 9x.

Comment: If you run a DOS boot with different directories, like winbootdir=c:\msdos and windir=c:\, you get all of the DOS drivers (himem,sys and ifshlp.sys) loading, winbootdir remains, the path does not include c:\msdos7\command.

Comment: Windows 95 runs compatible with Windows 3.1,  The directory where win,com is stored is where the INI files and so forth are stored.  That's so that you don't have to have a full OS on the user's home directory.  NT5 if installed over the top of Windows 9x, will create an MSDOS7 directory.  This is in effect, a 'DOS 7 without Windows'.  The msdos7 set up by nt, is effectively what Microsoft is wanting, and not some thirdparty hack.  I've used both Win31 and Win95 on networks, and seen how these are configure.  They are much the same.  win.com and winver is in the use directory.